# Can we loop through each cell in a databricks notebook

Tags: python, loops, databricks, azure-databricks

Say I have a collection

> col_name['ad','ac','hb']

I  have  to loop through this col_name in databricks python notebook to perform different transformation in cell. I have to perform every thing which is coded in each cell, only thing is the variable is getting changed for each loop.

```
Loop{ 

Cell1 

Cell2 

Cell3 

cell4 

}
```

Whether there is an option for the same or we need to bring all the transformations into 1 cell and have a loop